# Main Menu Button Grid iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface, uibutton, uicollectionview

There are plenty of good grid-of-button controls out there (such as [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView)) and tutorials around `UICollectionView` ([here](http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2014/05/uicollectionview-super-simple-example.html)).

However, they all seem to focus on imitating the look and feel of the Springboard of Photos app.

I'm looking for something that is more like the main menu you might see in a game. Where if I had one button, I want it to fill my view and be centered. Two buttons I would expect to share the space. Five buttons would have either a button on top (or below) a box of four buttons *centered*.

Is this sort of dynamic sizing of buttons to fill its parent container and centered of controls into columns easily accomplished with `UICollectionView` or would it be better to head down the path of something custom where I have a fixed layout support for, say, 1 - 5 button configurations.

Comment: I think it would be a lot easier going down the path of having fixed layout support rather than using a UICollectionView.

Comment: @Sean I kind of figured as such it just seems less flexible if I'm hard coding layout for 1 button, 2 buttons, 5 buttons, etc. I'd like to data drive this somehow (perhaps through a `plist` so its easy to edit but then I have to worry about orientation changes.